# image file is moved to its folder but image name not inserted into database

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, dropzone.js

I am creating a website, in users pages, I just wanted to add avatar (image), hence used Dropzone >>  js and css.

In my case, the PHP script moved the uploaded image into a folder successfully (without any error), but the image name is not inserted (updated) into my db table.

The `user` table has an avatar field for storage of the image name. 
If anyone can help, is really there error in below code or ....

uploads.php

```
include ('../fonfig/connection.php');
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$storeFolder = 'uploads';
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newname = time();
$dandom = rand(100, 999); 
$name = $newname.$random.'.'.$ext;
$query= "UPDATE users SET avatar = '$name' WHERE id=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
echo $query.'<br/>';
echo mysqli_error($dbc); 
if (!empty($_FILES)) {  
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
 $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
$targetFile =  $targetPath. $name;
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
?>
```

users.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(fucntion(){
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#avatar-dropzone");
});
</script>
<form action="uploads.php?id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" class="dropzone" id="avatar-dropzone">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, nothing error, but image name should inserted into my db table (user) in 'avatar ' field. Uploaded image has been moved to uploads folder, in uploads folder exist of image, in order to my $query, image name should also be saved to db, user table, this is not happening.

Comment: Does your db have any values with the same id that you are using to update?

Comment: no, only 1 user is now in my users table with id primary key.

Comment: then you should insert instead of updating